# Using Jquery Confirm in Laravel Form Open?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I have a Form written with the Laravel Form package.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\BlogController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'Confirm()' ]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Now I want this Jquery Code in this Form. I want that if the user clicks on the submit button, then the Jquery confirmation box should pop out.

Thats my Jquery:

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
  Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
});
```

Thats how I tried it:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Confirm()
            {
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                    Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
                });
            }


        </script>

{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Blog\\BlogController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'onsubmit' => 'Confirm()' ]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But this haven't worked for me. Any Help?

Comment: add `preventDefault()` to your jquery.

Comment: this just did nothing :/

Comment: First make sure that the submit button call `confirm` function by adding an alert before `bootbox.confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class `blog-form` for example :

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Blog\\BlogController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' =>
    'delete', 'class' => 'blog-form' ]) !!}
```

Then instead on using inline event `onsubmit` attach in your js code `submit` event to the added class `blog-form` and submit form in case of positive response :

```
$('.blog-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var blog_form = $(this);

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            blog_form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should work @WellNo make sure that you have included jquery library and check developpers console for errors.

Comment: Jquery is included and in the dev. console is just an:  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  --- I'm a beginner in things like JS/Jquery..

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $` mean that the Jquery is not correctly included.

Comment: Okay I included jquery with a CDN and now the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is gone. But it still does not work :/ The thread gets deleted but without any message

Comment: So try to debug your code using alerts, for example add an alert after `e.preventDefault();` to make sure that the `submit` event triggered.

Comment: I tried using a alert but of course if i click on the button, the whole thread gets deleted.

Comment: sorry for haven't reply :/ okay, I've got the package running and it works with some bugs. The confirm box pops out. If I cancle the confirmation, the window disappear, but if I'm pressing: Ok - then just another confirmation appears. over and over again. And I can't see why. My code is exactly like in this answer.